# How to have a normal External Drive recognized by the router through RJ45

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet, lan

I have a network problem that I would like to see if I'm missing something, and as such, here is the data:

**NEED**:
I wish to make a "server"-like WLAN/LAN setup with what I have now without having to spend money on a NAS server (out of box or bay) which is having prohibitive costs right now on my country.

**CURRENT SCENARIO**:
I currently have:

- HP ENVY 19
- 3 x 500Gb External 2.5' HD
- HITRON Wireless Router/Switch, with 1xUSB 1.0 + 4xLAN PORTS (last one capable of Bridge)

**IDEA**:
Somehow connect the USB 3.0 Ext HD into the LAN Ports through RJ45-USD converters and use SW or CONFIG to make the Router detect them (and the PC of course, so I can use them as a Network Drive just like a NAS or a pen drive)

Is this in anyway possible? Is there an alternative / easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance for all the help you can provide.

Best Regards
Luis Lima

Comment: Your external drives can be shared through the network as mapped drives in Windows, and as long as your laptop has an IP address, this should work fine. Are you trying to have them accessible even when the HP Envy is turned off?

Comment: Turn the HP Envy to an NAS? Get FreeNAS or so installed on it? Or is it the PC for your daily usage?

Comment: I didn't even know there were USB over IP hubs like http://www.amazon.com/CoolGear%C2%AE-Industrial-Network-4-Port-Device/dp/B00FBMSV5I  But at $100, he would be getting back into homebrew NAS territory

Comment: @Daedalus: Yes, basically network drives (accessible in a mobile for instance), I can plug them into the USB port (with a hub), but again, it's a ridiculous 1.5m/s transfer rate, it's USB 1.0 the version I have, that's why I wanted to use the LAN ports instead of the USB.

Comment: @TomYan: I don't want to buy the NAS and don't want the PC turned into a server, that's the point. It's expensive and I use the PC daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a homebuilt NAS, there are cheaper platforms you can build  one out of.

For instance, [this blog](http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/index.php/setting-up-a-samba-server-on-raspberry-pi/) shows a person building a Samba based one out of a Raspberry Pi.

Also, look around to see if there is a PC sitting in someone's closet (because its too old and slow), that may be fine as a lightweight server.  I've seen Raspberry Pis compared to old Pentium II machines.  There may actually be a real Pentium II system gathering dust near you.

But while this may be cheap in terms of money, it is not an ready-to-go solution.  You will probably spend some extra time setting it up, so consider how much money you value your own time.

Answer (score 0):

The first manual for a random Hitron device I looked at contained this:

> The CGN provides one USB 2.0 host port, allowing you
>
> to plug in a USB flash disk for mounting and sharing
>
> through the LAN interfaces via the Samba protocol
>
> (network neighborhood).
>
> The CGN supports the following Windows file systems:
>
> > FAT16
> >
> > FAT32
> >
> > NTFS

Maybe that will work for you

Comment: I don't suppose he can make use of THREE EXTERNAL drives with one USB 2.0 port though. Even if he got a RAID enclosure he will need to disassemble those drives.

Comment: This is true.  But trying a hub ito get more USB ports is an experiment I would try.  Maybe find an undocumented feature.  If internally it was Linux, it might just automount

Comment: I would be VERY surprise that if the router can handle multiple drives connected through a hub. How would it even mount them? Multiple Samba shares?

Comment: totally speculation,  but if it mounted them in a UFS sort of manner, what happens if you make a SMB share of UFS common mount point.   For example if you set up Samba on a Linux box to export `/mount`, and someone plugs in a USB stick, does it just automatically show up?   I have not played with samba enough to guess

Comment: UFS? You mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System ? Or UnionFS? Hmm if you mean the latter, maybe. At least overlayfs seems to be available in OpenWRT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS#Other_implementations

Comment: Well, I was think more of Unified File System,, the paradigm that unixes represent files to their applications by, as opposed to the more disjoint  drive letter and double-slash shares that windows uses.

Comment: To answer all: TOM: the USB is 1.0, not 2.0. That's why I am not even considering it. INFIXED I did the hub, I connected the three of them (my ISP actually uses the USB port to create a special network drive and shows each external drive as a lettered folder on Windows.) transfer rate is USB 1.0 or 1.5mb/s, ridiculous. UFS is going a bit overboard. I needed only a cheap way of connecting what I already have in an uncomplicated way, because any solution above $150 or so it goes into the WD MyCloud 2Tb NAS already, which is a solution out of a box. :) any other thoughts?

Comment: @INFIXED: What do you mean by CGN? I didn't get that.

Comment: Since no model number was given in the question, I found a manual for an access point made by that company.  First google hit that looked relevant. That manual refers to its product model as CGN

Comment: @INFIXED. Yeah my bad. here is the portuguese manual, but you can see the thing: http://teste.pgsite.com/delfim/Manual%20Modem%20HITRON.pdf - I think it's this one http://setuprouter.com/router/hitron-technologies/bvw-3653/

Comment: Might have been clearer of me to include a URL to the manual I was referencing.  I'll try to remember when doing similar ansers in the future

Comment: Still... no solutions you can think of?

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch up on comments and see you tried.   Your best bet may be to mount them on your HP, and let other people on the network share them.  It would mean you have to leave that computer on and on the network all the time.  If normal NAS is too much, maybe a Raspberry Pi  and Samba would do it for you.   This guy blogged about it http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/index.php/setting-up-a-samba-server-on-raspberry-pi/  let me know if I should make a new answer for that idea

Comment: @INFIXED yeah make that Raspberry PI a new answer and I'll mark it correct, it is something I had seen before and probably will try,,,

Comment: Starting to think I may need a second Switch here and bridge the first one...